# Pagination: How to display a long text as book pages?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, pagination

I have a very long text and I want to display it as a book in a web page. The user will use arrow keys to move forward and backward in same way like flipping pages of the book.

Leaving apart the transition of pages, how can this be achieved using jQuery?

What I thought was calculating the amount of text that will occupy the space on one page and then breaking the whole text into such pages and then displaying them. But it seems to be a bad idea for the space occupied will be platform dependent even if we fix the font.

One more problem that I was facing while using the space calculation method was due to the css justified display of text.

Has anyone done such thing before for a web page?

Comment: is the long text is in a database or file?

Comment: its mysql ... stored as text datatype ...

Comment: If your text is not already formatted/marked up, it's going to be very difficult to accomplish this and have it look good. If it is formatted/marked up you can use the PHP string functions to separate the text at sentences or paragraphs. Then a fluid layout should provide most of the structure.

Comment: it is a plain text with no html tags in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To layout a long string in a beautiful book page format. You need to get the exact string portion.  You can use this function.

```
function get_page($text, $page_index, $line_length=76, $page_length=40){
    $lines = explode("\n", wordwrap($texxt, $line_length, "\n"));
    $page_lines = array_slice($lines, $page_index*$page_length, $page_length);
    return implode("\n", $page_lines);
}

$line_length = 70;
$lines_per_page=50;
$page = 3;
$longtext= "...";

$page_text = get_page($longtext, $page-1, $line_length, $page_length);
```

**See [Demonstration](http://ideone.com/gslOod).**

### Example

**PHP**

```
$longtext = "..."; // it can be retrieved from sql as well.
$index=is_int($_GET['page'])? intval($_GET['page']): 1;
$line_length = 70;
$lines_per_page=50;
$longtext= "...";

$page_text = get_page($longtext, $index-1, $line_length, $page_length);
echo json_encode(array('text'=>$page_text));
```

**JQuery**

```
var nextPage=2;
$.get("getpage.php", { page: nextPage }, function(data){
   alert("text is "+data.text;
   // show the text data.text
});
```

Comment: it will not solve the problem ... there is no guarantee that a word will not be cut into half ... and also what about line breaks in the text

Comment: More likely he would want use `explode()` to provide an array of sentences or paragraphs.

Comment: @sri_wb There are functions to deal with it. Use [wordwrap](http://php.net/wordwrap).